# Underscore how to merge filtered objects or find two attribute in collection?

Tags: jquery, underscore.js

I have array of object, from I need to find the object which as 'age = 1' and 'name = one' then how to combine them both..

my try..

```
var array = [
    {'name':'one', "age":'3'},
    {'name':'two', "age":'1'},
    {'name':'three', "age":'3'},
    {'name':'four', "age":'1'},
    {'name':'one', "age":'7'}
]
var required = ['one', '1'];

var name = _.where(array, {'name':'one'});
var age = _.where(array, {'age':'1'});

var combine = $.extend({}, name, age ) 
console.log(combine); // getting only age based objects...
```

how to get the both attributed object even using underscore method itself?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kcnk3/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the [reduce](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce) function. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kcnk3/3/):

```
var combine = _.reduce(array, function(result, obj) {
    if (obj.name === 'one' || obj.age === '1') {result.push(obj);}
    return result;
}, []);
```

Comment: as well can you help me to remove the object based on array of values.. here is the demo.. http://jsfiddle.net/kcnk3/5/ how can i remove?

Comment: If I understand correctly - then you may use reduce again: http://jsfiddle.net/njhkr/

Answer (score 1):

The general filtering/searching function is [`_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter):

> **filter** `_.filter(list, iterator, [context])`
>
> Looks through each value in the **list**, returning an array of all the values that pass a truth test (**iterator**). Delegates to the native **filter** method, if it exists.

So you want:

```
_(array).filter(function(e) {
    return e.name === 'one' || e.age === '1';
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/aw2Hj/